# hardhat ethers getContractFactory how to look for custom directory?

Tags: solidity, hardhat

For the ethers plugin in hardhat, when I use `ethers.getContractFactory("<contract_name>")`, it looks for the abi and bytecode in the artifacts directory. However, is it possible to have the compiled json file stored in another directory, and specify it to have the getContractsFactory function look for it in that directory?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can load ABI, and Bytecode separately and call this method:

```
new ethers.ContractFactory( interface , bytecode [ , signer ] )
```

More info on [Ethers documentation](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/contract/contract-factory/#ContractFactory--creating)

Comment: So I have a json file (compiler output) with format as below:
```
test = {
  "_format": "hh-sol-artifact-1",
  "contractName": "<name>",
  "sourceName": "<name>",
  "abi": [
    ...
  ],
  "bytecode": "0x6080604052....."
}
```

When I use `ethers.ContractFactory(test.abi, test.bytecode)`, it gives me an invalid bytecode error. Any ideas what the format should be?

Comment: check that you import it correctly (check with console.log), data should be `contractFactory.bytecode ⇒ string< DataHexString >`